# Nesting of FOR XML Expressions

Tags: t-sql, for-xml

I tried a FOR XML query similar to what's shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345137%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) under the subtitle 'Nesting of FOR XML Expressions'. My problem is that I have to have three XML element levels. The results should be something like this.

```
<StepTree Name="ALFKI">
  <Step Name="Foo">
    <Result id="123" />
    <Result id="456" />
  </Step>
  <Step Name="Bar">
    <Result id="789" />
    <Result id="987" />
  </Step>
</StepTree >
```

I tried this type of query.

```
SELECT 1 as TAG,
       NULL as Parent,
       StepTrees.Name AS [StepTree!1!Name],
       NULL as [Step!2!Name],
       NULL as [Result!3!id]
FROM StepTrees
WHERE StepTrees.Name = 'ALFKI' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       1,
       StepTrees.Name,
       Steps.Name,
       NULL
FROM Steps
JOIN StepTrees ON Steps.StepTreeId = StepTrees.Id
WHERE StepTrees.Name = 'ALFKI' 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 3,
       2,
       StepTrees.Name,
       Steps.Name,
       Results.id
FROM StepTrees
JOIN Steps ON Steps.StepTreeId = StepTrees.Id
JOIN Results ON Steps.StepId = Results.StepId
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

The resulting XML is as follows.

```
<StepTree Name="ALFKI">
  <Step Name="Foo" />
  <Step Name="Bar">
    <Result id="123" />
    <Result id="456" />
    <Result id="789" />
    <Result id="987" />
  </Step>
</StepTree >
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this query:

```
SELECT 1 as TAG,
   NULL as Parent,
   StepTrees.Name AS [StepTree!1!Name],
   NULL as [Step!2!Name],
   NULL as [Result!3!id]
FROM StepTrees
WHERE StepTrees.Name = 'ALFKI' 
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,
       1,
       Null,
       Steps.Name,
       NULL
FROM Steps
JOIN StepTrees ON Steps.StepTreeId = StepTrees.Id
WHERE StepTrees.Name = 'ALFKI' 
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT 3,
       2,
       Null,
       Steps.Name,
       Results.id
FROM StepTrees
JOIN Steps ON Steps.StepTreeId = StepTrees.Id
JOIN Results ON Steps.StepId = Results.StepId
ORDER BY [Step!2!Name],[Result!3!id]
FOR XML EXPLICIT
```

Comment: Yup, that works as long as I add the same WHERE clause to the last SELECT as well. Didn't know about the effect ORBER BY has on the the shape of the XML. Thank you so much. -- Rubio